# Expanding multiple-value abbreviations in Sublime Text 3 using Emmet

Tags: css, sublimetext3, sublimetext, emmet

Using latest build of ST3 3083. I suppose, it's using latest version of Emmet plugin (btw, I've checked it in Package Control: List Packages - v.2015.10.29).

I want to expand multiple values abbreviation. So, **m10-20** becomes **margin: 10px 20px**. But then I press TAB - nothing happens. Console is empty too.

**m10** happily transform into **margin: 10px;**

The thing is, that official docs ([here](http://docs.emmet.io/css-abbreviations/)) saying it is possible and should actually work as intended.

How to make this thing work? Thanks!

Comment: PHPStorm allows me to pull this off. I'm consider it ST issue and investigate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me in `ST3 3083` with `Emmet v.2015.10.29`. There must be something wrong with your setup.

**Make sure your syntax is set to css.**

If it's still not working, reinstall Emmet.

Comment: Thanks for feedback! I'm looking forward to examine it later.